# Unable to get browser to store session-cookie using fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, session-cookies

I've made a Node.js API using the express framework. The API supports a POST-request to /login, where the client should include email and password formatted as JSON in the body. The API will then return a session cookie via the setCookie-header.

I DO see the cookie coming back from the API as a `response-cookie`, however, the browser isn't storing it, and therefore it is not sent with further requests from the client. I've tried using `{credentials: include}` since this is a CORS-request. I've also added the `cors-module` in my node-server (API) to handle the OPTIONS (pre-flight) requests. I've used so many hours trying to figure this out, so any help would be much appreciated.

Side-note: This works completely fine in both Postman and a prototype iOS-app I've developed using the same API, so there shouldn't be any issues on the server itself.

I've included relevant code from the server and the front-end below.

Code from server:

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: ['http://expivider.dk', 'http://expivider.herokuapp.com', 'https://expivider.herokuapp.com', 'http://api.expivider.dk']}));
app.use(session({
cookieName: 'session',
secret: SECRET_HERE,
duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
cookie: {
    // path: '/api', cookie will only be sent to requests under '/api'
    maxAge: 60000, // duration of the cookie in milliseconds, defaults to duration above
    ephemeral: false, // when true, cookie expires when the browser closes
    httpOnly: false, // when true, cookie is not accessible from javascript
    secure: false, // when true, cookie will only be sent over SSL. use key 'secureProxy' instead if you handle SSL not in your node process
    path: "/"
    //domain: "expivider.herokuapp.com"
 }
}));
```

Code from front-end:

```
const handleRequestWithBodyWithCredentials = function (method, url, body, callback) {
fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    mode: 'cors'
}).then((resp) => (resp.json())).then(function (data) {
    callback(data);

});

};

const validate = function () {

    let em = document.login.username.value;
    let pw = document.login.password.value;

    let body = {
        'email': em,
        'password': pw
    };

    handleRequestWithBodyWithCredentials('post', LOGIN_NEW, body, showCompanyStats);

    console.log();
};
```

Note: Right now, the front-end is hosted on 'http://expivider.dk', and it makes calls to the api at 'http://api.expivider.dk' (which is actually hosted at 'expivider.herokuapp.com' but I'm using a custom-domain).

Please let me know if you need any more info to help me out!

Comment: You're not specifying the domain for the cookie, so it defaults to "expivider.dk" and will not be sent to the subdomain.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, I've tried adding `{domain: "api.expivider.dk"}`, but I still cannot get it to work. You can see (in the screenshots below) that the domain is set now, but the cookie still doesn't seem to be stored and is not sent with my future requests:
[link to screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/RyP3y)

Comment: You probably should set the domain to "expivider.dk", which will then work for that domain *and* for "api.expdivider.dk".  What do you see when you look at the cookies with the browser "view cookies" tool? Is it actually setting the cookie?